# convert a string in to int in c

Tags: c++, c

I have a string having 12 characters in it, and want to convert that in int or we can say digit , but not able to do it. i have written a code which converts string up to 11 digits but after that it starts giving garbage value.
my code is like

```
#include<stdio.h>
double myAtoi(char *str);
void main()
{
    double n;
    double m;
    char* a="12345678912";
    char* b="34";
    n=myAtoi(a);
    //m=atoi(b);
    printf("\nconversion is : %d",(n));
}

double myAtoi(char *str)
{   
    printf("\nstr : %s",str);
    long res = 0; // Initialize result
    long i ;
    // Iterate through all characters of input string and update result
    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        res = res*10 + str[i] - '0';
        printf("\n res : %d",res);
        //x=res;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: A c++ answer would be radically different. Are you sure that you want those? If not, then how is c++ relevant to this question?

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: I suspect you mean `return res;` as there's nothing called "x" in that code. And your `printf` format string is wrong, so you'll probably print rubbish even if you fix that.

Comment: @ Aniket Amrutkar is your problem solved.?

Comment: Yes.. @ameyCU had given me the correct answer..

Answer (score 3):

Bugs:

- What is `x`? Where is it declared? Why have you commented out the code copying `res` into x? Why did you copy it inside the loop instead of at the end of the function? You don't even need `x`, merely `return (double)res;` if you insist on using double, for reasons unknown.
- 12345678912 is 12.3 billion. Usually a `long` can only fit 2^32 / 2 = 2.14 billion as largest number. Consider using `long long`.
- You are printing long and double with `%d` conversion specifier which is wrong in both cases.
- You probably don't even want to use double in this program, it doesn't make any sense.

Other things:

- Since this is a hosted system, main must be declared as `int main (void)`. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31263079/584518).
- Always declare pointers to string literals as `const char*`. Because you will never write to a string literal, only read from it.
- The parameter to your function should also be declared as `const char*`, for const correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that `long` cannot hold number as big as "12345678912"  instead use 
`unsigned long long` .

Its specifier is  `"%llu"`.

And also in your code `x` is  not delared instead use `return res;`

As you use `unsigned long long` you need to change definition of  function `double myatoi()`  to  `unsigned long long myatoi()` -

Your program can be re-written as below -

```
#include<stdio.h>
unsigned long long myAtoi(char *str);
int main()
{

   unsigned long long  n; // Note here n also changed from double to unsigned long long
   double m;
   char* a="12345678912";
   char* b="34";
   n=myAtoi(a);
   //m=atoi(b);
   printf("\nconversion is : %llu",(n));
}

   unsigned long long myAtoi(char *str)
{   

   printf("\nstr : %s",str);
   unsigned long long res = 0; // Initialize result
   long i ;
   // Iterate through all characters of input string and update result
   for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) 
  {
       res = res*10 + str[i] - '0';
       printf("\n res : %llu",res);
       //x=res; 
  }
     return res;
}
```

Comment: @AniketAmrutkar General rule if it helped accept the answer , No worries go up with your program :).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you cannot hold "12345678912"  to a long variable.
please refer 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm

the maximum value that can hold for a long variable is -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

and you are returning wrong value from your method.return res instead of x.no need of x in that code.

Comment: C specifies the _minimum_, range of `long` is -2,147,483,647 to 2,147,483,647.  C does not specified its maximum range.  `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647` is common range.